# Problems With Simple captcha

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I have a weird issue .I am using simple captcha  in forms in my rails applications. If I am using one captcha in a web page I don't have any problem. But I have a scenario of using three(3) forms in one page in which all the three forms will have the captcha . So that when I refresh the page the captcha data of the three forms are equal.

When we come to database , once the page get loaded the captcha value for one particular id will be created, Without using the captcha if we refresh the page the record is getting updated instead of creating another record, And more over if I open the web page in two tabs and if  I submit the form in the first page. It throws an exception which says “ Invalid Captcha”

Can anyone please let me know how to handle multiple captcha's in single page. I am using simple_captcha plugin.

Thanks in-advance

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any point using more than one captcha for one page. (I assume that both your forms will submit at the same time.) Because the whole purpose of captcha is to avoid the automatic form submissions.

The second point is, I'm not sure why you want three forms in a single page. You might consider having a one form and filter the identify the parameters accordingly in the controller side.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain why do you need new record instead of updated (while refreshing page).

By the way, I had same issue with multiply forms on one page handled by simple_captcha. And my problem was in repeated use of simple_captcha's method `show_simple_captcha`. It caused repeated database insertions in this case. And Ive made minor changes to the plugin to solve this:

```
# Line 73 in lib/simple_captcha/view_helpers.rb (in show_simple_captcha method)

options[:field_value] = set_simple_captcha_data(simple_captcha_key, options[:code_type])
```

changed to:

```
options[:field_value] = options[:multi] ? simple_captcha_key : set_simple_captcha_data(simple_captcha_key, options[:code_type])
```

Now I use `show_simple_captcha(:multi => true)` to generate captcha without database hitting:

```
<!-- For first captcha on page -->
<%= show_simple_captcha(:object => :foo) %>

<!-- For next captchas on same page -->
<%= show_simple_captcha(:object => :bar, :multi => true) %>
```