# rails multiple simple_captcha in a single page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have two seperate forms in a single page and using [simple_captcha](https://github.com/galetahub/simple-captcha) gem for human verification using this line of code in two forms:

```
<%= show_simple_captcha %>
```

But the verification code in two forms are same and I am validating these using this method.

```
simple_captcha_valid?
```

How can I use two separate verification code in two forms in a single page? Both form will be submitted to two different actions.

Comment: See a same discussion here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683920/problems-with-simple-captcha

Comment: I have tried it. The second answer doesn't work.

Comment: If possible then, load the second form after saving the first form . It may be a solution.